# SSD failed, mdadm thinks the RAID0 array is fine

Tags: linux, debian, raid, mdadm

I have a RAID0 array created using mdadm in Debian. sdf is the drive that died.

`$ cat /proc/mdstat`

```
md4 : active raid0 sdf1[1] sde1[0]
      468859904 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

`$ mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md4`

```
/dev/md4:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : <...>
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 468859904 (447.14 GiB 480.11 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : <...>
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : server:4  (local to host server)
           UUID : <...>
          Events : 0

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1
   1       8       81        1      active sync
```

`$ file /dev/sdf`

```
/dev/sdf: ERROR: cannot open `/dev/sdf' (No such file or directory)
```

`$ tail /var/log/messages`

```
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696833] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 e0 88 50 00 00 30 00
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696903] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf] Device not ready
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696906] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696909] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696912] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf]  Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
Feb 24 08:03:32 server kernel: [33166523.696916] sd 0:0:5:0: [sdf] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 05 e0 88 90 00 00 08 00
```

Things of note:

- The message in /var/log/messages repeats hundreds of times over the course of a couple minutes, and then stops.
- mdadm doesn't think the array has failed.
- The blank spot at the bottom of `mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md4` where /dev/sdf1 should be.
- The block device /dev/sdf no longer exists.
- I cannot manually mark the drive as failed in the array because /dev/sdf doesn't exist.

As a result of mdadm thinking that the array is fine, I never got an alert that the drive had failed. What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Hotplug) says:

> - If the physical disk is dead or unplugged, just do
>
>   ```
>   mdadm /dev/mdX --fail detached --remove detached
>   ```

Comment: Tried this, the command returns `mdadm: set device faulty failed for 8:81:  Device or resource busy`, 8:81 being sdf (the dead drive)

Comment: Wait... It's raid0. That means you whole array failed. You have to stop the array, because mdadm won't let you remove components of raid0 device: see this thread:  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mdadm-fails-to-hot-remove-disk-657518/

Comment: Right, but why wasn't the array marked as failed automatically? When a drive fails in a RAID1 array, mdadm sends an email alert. However, in this case, mdadm says that the array is fine, so no alert would have been sent.

Comment: @IanLing: I have no idea mdadm thinks the array is "clean". What `cat /proc/mdadm` says about it?

Comment: See the `mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md4` part in the question, it shows `State : clean`

Comment: @IanLing: Yes, I saw it. I was just curious what is written in `/proc/mdadm` in such weird situation.

Comment: /proc/mdstat is at the top of the question, I don't seem to have a /proc/mdadm